# Removing double brackets to single brackets from arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, stream, hashmap

The purpose of this code is to count the instances of letters that occur in sequence, using HashMaps, and Streams.

The code prints out

```
<[[is=3,imple=2,it=1]]>
```

but I need it to pass this test

```
assertEquals("is=3_imple=2_it=1_".replace("_", ls), out);
```

I've tried using .toString() to fix this problem but removing a set of brackets using .replace() causes the expected result to change to

```
<is=3[
imple=2
it=1
]>
```

and my actual code to print

```
<is=3[,imple=2,it=1]>
```

I've tried removing commas using .replace in the toString() as well but I feel like i'm hardcoding the answer at that point.

Any advice on how I should proceed ? Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class WordCount {

protected Map<String, Integer> counts;
static Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

public WordCount(){

    counts = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

}
public Map getCounts(){

    return counts;
}

public int parse(Scanner in, Pattern pattern){
        int counter=0;
        while   (in.hasNext())  {
        //  get the next    token
        String  token   =   in.next();
        //  match   the pattern within  the token
        Matcher matcher =   pattern.matcher(token);
        //  process each    match   found   in  token   (could  be  more    than    one)
        while   (matcher.find())    {
                        //  get the String  that    matched the pattern
            String  s   =   matcher.group().trim();
                        //  now do  something   with    s

            counter=counts.containsKey(s) ? counts.get(s):0;
            counts.put(s,counter+1);
            }

        }


        return counter;
}


public void report(PrintStream printstream){
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> results= new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();

    results.addAll(counts.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(results,   Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));

    String aList = results.toString();

    aList = results.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    printstream.print(aList);
}





}



//Test Case

enter code here
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestWordCount extends TestCase {
public void test_WordCount_parse() {
    WordCount wc = new WordCount();
    Scanner in = new Scanner("this is a simple test, but it is not simple to pass");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[i][a-z]+");
    wc.parse(in, pattern);

    assertEquals((Integer)3, wc.getCounts().get("is"));
    assertEquals((Integer)2, wc.getCounts().get("imple"));
    assertEquals((Integer)1, wc.getCounts().get("it"));

}

public void test_WordCount_report() {
    WordCount wc = new WordCount();
    Scanner in = new Scanner("this is a simple test, but it is not simple to pass");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[i][a-z]+");
    wc.parse(in, pattern);

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wc.report(new PrintStream(output));
    String out = output.toString();
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();

    assertEquals("is=3_imple=2_it=1_".replace("_", ls), out);
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have "_" in your assert? Cant you just check with the commas. And why the line separator?

Comment: Just because I am going to be applying this code to a .txt file of scripts in order to count the occurrence of the individual words and want them parsed with new lines in between each for legibility.

Comment: Right, but you are asserting after you replace the "_".  For legibility you can format that after the test.

Answer (score 0):

After the following line is run in the test_WordCount_report() method : **String out = output.toString().** The output should look like this:

```
is=3, imple=2, it=1
```

So you should be able to directly assert that or if you need to keep that specific assertion string, change the assert check like so:

```
String assertValue = "is=3_imple=2_it=1_";
String updAssert = assertValue.substring(0,assertValue.length() - 1).replace("_", ", ");
assertEquals(updAssert, out);
```

Later on in the code you can append the updAssert (if it passed) to a string builder and then append a new line.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(updAssert).append(System.lineSeparator());
```

Comment: To fix my problem what I ended up doing is removing the .toString() replacing it with .toArray()  and using a for loop to iterate the printstream.print

Thank you so much for your help!